# Add Excel Expressions to a SQL Query Result

Tags: sql-server, excel

I have a requirement where I need to execute a SQL Query which will be outputted to a .csv file. This will will then be opened in Excel. The data can then be manipulated in the spreadsheet and values automatically updated in computed columns (thanks to Excel expressions)

Here's an example:

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
1        | 2        | A+B
4        | 10       | A+B
         | 12       | A+B
0        | 1        | A+B
```

Column C is simple Column A + Column B, however I cannot simply write this in the query, as the purpose of the spreadsheet is to **allow someone to edit columns A and B in Excel and then Column C will automatically be updated**.

I've thought about including the Row Number in the query and writing Column C as "=A{N}+B{N}" where N is the row index.

Is it possible to achieve something like this?

Comment: Did you try to do that? It sounds logical.

Comment: Yeah, I wasn't sure how to get the row number. Looks like someone has answered that. I'll try it out and see how well it goes. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like you already have a plan:

```
SELECT [COLUMN A], [COLUMN B], 'A' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR) + '+B' + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS VARCHAR) AS [COLUMN C]
FROM [TABLE1]
```

Comment: I've just tried that myself - works like a charm. OP should remember that he has to deal with NULLs over there.

Comment: Just thinking that myself. Nothing a good old ISO standard COALESCE won't sort out.

Comment: That's right. And another thought - maybe increasing `ROW_NUMBER` value by 1 in each row would be handy in case user wants to keep table headers.