# How can I import Excel cell reference or formula store in SQL table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel

I have the following SQL table.

[image]

I imported this table into Excel sheet by following
Data-->Get Data-->Database-->Import from SQL database

On the Excel sheet, I have income calculated in cell J1. 
I want to give reference of cell J1 in my SQL table which I have done above.
Excel output is

[image]

In cell C2 cell reference/formula is importing from SQL table and in cell C4 it is written directly.
It is not working in cell C2 but the same formula is working on cell C4.
How can I bring cell reference or formula from the SQL table?

Comment: SQL tables don't have cells, cell "C2" and "C4" means nothing Database terms. Especially when the table you show us only has 1 row.

Comment: Thanks, Larnu for your reply. I am trying to bring =INDIRECT("J1") from SQL query instead of typing it directly. In theory, it should work?

Comment: I have a big table in SQL having 25 columns. When I brought this data into Excel sheet, values in one of my columns is updated from another cell in Excel sheet. I want to give a reference from my SQL table.to this sheet.

Comment: Your question is unclear. What is your desired result? Are you showing it in first image? Otherwise, you may be conflating Excel software with relational database features.

Comment: @Parfait- I am doing other way round, I am bringing this formula from SQL table to Excel. Do you want me to put single quote in formula in SQL table.

Comment: My desired result is, I only want to place the formula in cell C3 from SQL table instead of typing it. which I got in Excel sheet but this is not working.

Comment: *"I only want to place the formula in cell C3 from SQL table instead of typing it"* Your SQL Table has no "Cell" C3, like i said before. Cells don't exist in SQL, you have rows and columsn, but not cells. Even if they did, "C3" would refer to the 3rd row in the 3rd column; your SQL table has 1 row, so has no "cell" C3...

Comment: My SQL table has only 1 row because I am replicating my problem in a simple way.

Comment: Ok. forget C3 and C4.  what I am trying to do that when my result will import in XL, cell having the formula =INDIRECT("J1") should act as formula just like I typed in =INDIRECT('J1') in Excel.

Comment: In my second fig, C2 having formula =INDIRECT("J1") - imported from SQL table & C4 has the same formula typed in Excel. First one is not working, Second one is working

Answer (score 0):

There is a quick way to do evaluate the formula in Excel after refreshing the data from the SQL server.

Replace `=` with `=` in Excel. It's the same character but it evaluates the formula.

[image]

[image]

I found this interesting answer in another [SO answer post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305112/returning-an-excel-expression-from-a-sql-query-used-in-excel). You can also create a macro and run it every time after refreshing the data as described in another answer in the same link.